# Intel Fortran Compiler (ifort) suppress specific warning message

Tags: compilation, fortran, intel-fortran

Is it possible to suppress specific warning message in `ifort` compiler still having other warnings turned on? To be more specific, I want to switch off the following warning message:

> warning #7601: F2008 standard does not allow an internal procedure to be an
>      actual argument procedure name. (R1214.4).

(by the way, this is some issue related to the F2008 standard implementation within [`ifort`](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/486629)). I'm using `ifort 13.0.1 20121010` on a Linux machine.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed by Intel Fortran 14.0.1.139 so updating your compiler is one option to consider.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the other story since this construct is allowed in f08 standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the -diag-disable nnn option (/Qdiag-disable:nnn on Windows), where nnn is the number of the warning (7601 here) that you want to suppress.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible. You can turn on/off all warnings separately.

I'm not sure what the correct keyword for this particular warning is, my guess would be `-warn nostderrors`...

You can find the extensive list of `warn` options [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/compiler-diagnostic-options/warn.html).

Comment: I cannot suppress this warning having `-warn all` flag on. On the other hand I can switch `-warn none` and turn standard warnings to errors with `-warn stderrors`. `[no]stderrors` just "Determines whether warnings about Fortran standard violations are changed to errors."

Comment: Link died unfortunately

Comment: @Mark Thanks! I found another site with the list of options to `-warn`.